# How batchUpdate locks tables/rows

Tags: java, jdbc, batch-processing, jdbctemplate, spring-jdbc

Could any one help me with this question:
If I execute JDBC **batchUpdate**, which updates several tables and is not wrapped into any transactions, will it lock any tables or rows?

My code executes a bunch of UPDATE statements and all of them look as follows

```
    String sql = "UPDATE contacts SET ref_counter = ? where uid = ?";
    jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(sql, new CustomBatchPreparedStatementSetter(elements));
```

Any link to documentation will be appreciated (I haven't managed to find any...)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post the sql for the batchUpdate?

Comment: it executes a bunch of UPDATE statements and all of them look as follows
UPDATE contacts SET ref_counter = ? where uid = ?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. Could edit your question to include the Java code executing the batchUpdate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Locking (if any) is implementation dependent, so not defined by JDBC itself.